# How to wait for Zalenium service ready state in docker-compose file?

Tags: zalenium

I'm using zalenium using docker-compose file for executing my test case. But my test cases are failing because of zalenium service not in a ready state.

I tried a couple of options like the WAIT_FOR_HOSTS option of docker-compose but the issue is zalenium grid is getting started at port 4444 and nodes are not yet registered. which takes some time to in a ready state

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the section `Waiting for Zalenium to be ready` at https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/